# Is there a anyway to make redis key value decrease by 1 over time?

Tags: redis

I want to use only 1 key value pair in Redis database. and the value will be decreased by 1 in every 60 seconds. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interesting question :) Yes, you can do that with a trick.

As we known Redis TTL can be decreased automatically over time. So you can use TTL as the value, and the TTL will decrease by 1 every second.

Say, you want to set a value of `N`, in order to achieve your goal, you can set a key-value pair with expiration `TTL = 60 * N`:

```
SET key N EX TTL
```

When you want to get the value, just get its TTL, and do some math:

```
ttl = TTL key

if (ttl > 0)
   value = ttl / 60 + 1
else
   // no longer exist
```

Comment: That's a shameless hack - loving it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm wondering is there any chance that I can increase TTL by 1 during its count down? or just edit, manipulate value of TTL? :)

Comment: @Erdenee Yes, you can use the EXPIRE command to reset the TTL. Of course, you need to get the current TTL first, increase it, and call EXPIRE to reset the TTL.